# Change event before it propagates to next listener?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way change an event and let it propagate further with the change?

For example how can I "force" press `shift` when any key is pressed?

```js
window.focus();

window.addEventListener("keypress", e =>
{
  //force shift key doesn't work
  e.shiftKey = true;
})

window.addEventListener("keypress", e =>
{
  console.log("shift", e.shiftKey);
});
```

*(this is just an example, I'm looking for a general solution that would work with any type of event)*

Comment: You can't "change" a KeyboardEvent. It's read-only.

Comment: But perhaps I can somehow "clone" the event with the changes?

Comment: You can create a new event and emit that but the new event would be processed as a unique event, separate from the original, and that new event would not be [trusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted).

Comment: @vanowm I didn't clone.. I edit the event object before it passes down

Comment: also, @Ouroborus it is trusted still xD

Comment: What is the higher level problem you are actually trying to solve here?

Comment: at https://messages.google.com/web/ when writing a message, hitting `Enter` sends the message, but `Shift` + `Enter` it enters a new line. I want make it do the opposite: `Enter` key enters a new line, while `Shift` + `Enter` sends the message.

Comment: @vanowm my answer is suited to do EXACTLY that ;-;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can't "change" a KeyboardEvent. It's read-only.

It took a while, but apparently it IS the same object that gets passed to all the event listeners.. I messed with the `get` properties of `Event` and `KeyboardEvent` and the edited event passes smoothly :D

```js
window.focus();

function control(event){
  const eventMap=new WeakMap()
  const getMap=(instance,key)=>{
    let map=eventMap.get(instance)
    if(!map){
      map={[key]:{value:null,valueSet:false}}
      eventMap.set(instance,map)
    }
    if(!map[key]){map[key]={value:null,valueSet:false}}
    return map[key] //specific to an event instance AND key
  }
  if(typeof event=='function'){event=event.prototype}
  let properties=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(event)
  Object.keys(properties)
  .filter(key=>
    typeof(properties[key].get)=='function'
  )
  .forEach(key=>{
    const original=properties[key].get
    function set(something){
      let map=getMap(this,key)
      map.value=something; map.valueSet=true
    }
    function get(){
      let {value,valueSet}=getMap(this,key)
      return valueSet? value: original.call(this)
    }
    properties[key]={...properties[key],get,set}
  })
  Object.defineProperties(event,properties)
}
//for any event class given to it, this function makes its prototype functions malleable
control(KeyboardEvent); control(Event)
//not all but A LOT of the prototypes including shiftKey fall under these 2 classes

//eventListener that I assume you control and add first
window.addEventListener("keypress", e =>
{
  e.shiftKey=!e.shiftKey //your edit to the event(switches the shiftKey event locally and not globally)
})

//event listener that might be in the environment that you didn't make
window.addEventListener("keypress", e =>
{
  console.log("shift", e.shiftKey); //false when u use shift, true when u don't use shift now >:D
});

console.log("press an unshifted letter in this area")
```

@vanoworm, for your electron app.. here's a working example of an event edit working smoothly

**EDIT**
I saw your response

> basically it changes `shiftKey` property globally for all future events, not only for current one.

Thank you for telling me.. I just fixed that and also.. about `control.js`, it can just be a string on your backend since it's meant to execute on the browser ;-; my bad

**index.js**

```js
var control=require('./control.js')
const {BrowserWindow,app} = require('electron')
app.on('ready',()=>{
  const win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 })
  let script=control+'\ncontrol(Event); control(KeyboardEvent)\n'
  +'window.addEventListener("keypress",e=>e.shiftKey=true)\n'
  +'window.addEventListener("keypress",e=>console.log(e.shiftKey))\n'
  +'console.log("press an unshifted letter in this browser")'
  win.webContents.executeJavaScript(script)
  win.loadURL('https://github.com')
})
```

**control.js**

```js
module.exports=`
function control(event){
  const eventMap=new WeakMap()
  const getMap=(instance,key)=>{
    let map=eventMap.get(instance)
    if(!map){
      map={[key]:{value:null,valueSet:false}}
      eventMap.set(instance,map)
    }
    if(!map[key]){map[key]={value:null,valueSet:false}}
    return map[key] //specific to an event instance AND key
  }
  if(typeof event=='function'){event=event.prototype}
  let properties=Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(event)
  Object.keys(properties)
  .filter(key=>
    typeof(properties[key].get)=='function'
  )
  .forEach(key=>{
    const original=properties[key].get
    function set(something){
      let map=getMap(this,key)
      map.value=something; map.valueSet=true
    }
    function get(){
      let {value,valueSet}=getMap(this,key)
      return valueSet? value: original.call(this)
    }
    properties[key]={...properties[key],get,set}
  })
  Object.defineProperties(event,properties)
}
`
```

Comment: Might want to check cross browser. Some browsers use a global event object while others don't

Comment: can u give me an example of browers that would replicate event objects instead of passing them along? I would like to test out a solution on that browser

Comment: because I am able to dispatch an edited event that is trusted.. however I cannot prevent the original event from being dispatched **before** the edited event gets deployed.. so it seems that editing the event when u catch it first is the best approach I can get FOR NOW.. just tested 3 other browsers and it works smoothly as well

Comment: Thank you. works well in browser. I'm actually need this for `electron` application which, it's not as straight forward as this, so it seems.

Comment: well.. u gotta find a way of adding your event listener before the app's.. in a browser I'd open a puppet window to execute my code first.. but since you're the client there should be a way to add your event listener first ;-; cuz I have no electron experience unfortunately.. I might begin learning electron now tho

Comment: @vanowm check it out.. it works in electron as well >:D

Comment: Thank you. I failed to mention that I use typescript and electron...and it's very strict with variable types, had to use bunch of `//@ts-ignore` to make it work.

Comment: There is an issue with your code. If you change `e.shiftKey` only when pressed `enter` key, after it pressed, pressing any other key will also show that the shift is true, basically it changes `shiftKey` property globally for all future events, not only for current one.

Comment: @vanowm Thank you for telling me.. I just fixed that.. check now >:D

Comment: Your code works very well, even though in my particular case it doesn't...the previous version with "global" events worked...I must be missing something on my end. Thank you for the code, I'm sure other will find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use strict mode to see why your code isn't working:

```js
'use strict';
window.focus();

window.addEventListener("keypress", e =>
{
  //force shift key doesn't work
  e.shiftKey = true;
})

window.addEventListener("keypress", e =>
{
  console.log("shift", e.shiftKey);
});
```

The event that the browser passes to `addEventListener` (regardless of propagation status) can't have certain intrinsic properties changed, including `shiftKey`. While you could assign to a different non-reserved property of the event, a better approach I think would be to use a WeakMap that maps the event to the new propert(ies) you want.

```js
'use strict';
const customPropertiesByEvent = new WeakMap();
window.focus();

window.addEventListener("keypress", e =>
{
  customPropertiesByEvent.set(e, { shift: true });
})

window.addEventListener("keypress", e =>
{
  console.log("shift", customPropertiesByEvent.get(e).shift);
});
```

Comment: that's assuming that both event listeners *know* to look at the WeakMap `customPropertiesByEvent`

Comment: Well, if you can't modify the event listeners in the first place, you can't really change anything about them to make them work anyway...

Comment: The problem is I can't change the other listeners.

Comment: @vanowm If you can't modify the listeners, there isn't really any decent way to fix them. Have to be able to change the code in order to fix the code to do what you want.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it ain't impossible >:D